# Turtlebot NUC battery state

Tags: ros, battery, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,

I'd like to use the turtlebot with a more powerful NUCi5 instead of a poor netbook.
The NUC has no /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1

Is it possible to replace it with simply setting:
export TURTLEBOT_BATTERY=/var/tmp/battery/BAT1

and write my own file for battery simulation/fake ?
Later I'd like to fill-up the content with real data from an attached external USB-ADC-Modul.

Which parameters/values are neccessary to make default turtlebot happy with the fake-setup ?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks for some feedback

Cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251275/turtlebot-nuc-battery-state/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2017-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you'd like to setup a way to generate a battery status that would be interesting. Note that we've recently added support to disable the battery monitoring too: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/blob/kinetic/turtlebot_bringup/launch/minimal.launch#L21

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0